# How can my Rails code tell whether it is running in a server (e.g. thin) or in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, thin, eventmachine, faye

It turns out that the thin server is very particular about starting the EventMachine reactor for itself. That would be fine except that there are circumstances where I need to start the reactor because the process is not being run inside of thin.

So the simple question is how can I programatically determine that my Rails application is being started by a thin server?  In that case I won't start my own EventMachine reactor, otherwise I have to.

Answer (score 1):

After walking through both Rails and Thin initialization, it appears that there really is no penetration into the `Application` instance from `Thin::Server`.  That seems to mean that I can't examine my app in order to see the server running it.

So I simply opted to check whether `Thin::Server` was defined. Since I have thin loaded with:

```
gem 'thin', require: false
```

I'm only going to have the `Thin::Server` class initialized if the application is being started from thin.  I've checked the rails console, rake tasks and delayed_jobs workers and the assumption seems to hold.

So, in my application.rb:

```
# Start Faye...
config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock

thin_server = defined?(Thin::Server)

config.after_initialize do |app|
  Faye.logger = Rails.logger

  unless thin_server
    Faye.logger.debug "Ensure reactor running!"
    Faye.ensure_reactor_running!
  end
end

faye_params = {mount: '/faye', timeout: 25}
faye_params[:server] = 'thin' if thin_server

config.middleware.use FayeRails::Middleware, faye_params
```

Comment: What if i don't use Faye as middleware? I start it behind AWS balancer in ELB container, so i cannot use it as middleware